# Is $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]^{2}] = \mathbb{E}[Y]^{2}$?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I am really sorry to ask such basis questions, but I am unable to find needed information on properties of expectation operator anywhere:

Is $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]^{2}] = \mathbb{E}[Y]^{2}$ ?

Comment: The short answer is no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Z=E[Y|X]$. Then, $E(Z)=E(Y)$, and we have
$$
E[Y]^2=E[Z]^2\leq E[Z^2]=E[E(Y|Z)^2]
$$
so what you have is an **inequality** instead of an equality. The inequality is strict whenever $Z$ has positive variance so an easy example can be obtained by considering $(X,Y)$ bivariate normal in which case $Z$ is an affine transformation of $X$ with generally positive variance.

Comment: I can not understand why $E[Z^2]=E[E(Y|Z)^2]$. I thought that it will be either $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]^{2}] = \mathbb{E}[Y]^{2}$ using law of total expectation or $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]*[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]], which is impossible to simplify any further, since it is an expectation of a product of two random variables. Can you please explain how you get $E[Z^2]=E[E(Y|Z)^2]$ ?

Comment: @user0347284  
$E[Z^2]=E[E(Y|X)^2]$ is just substituting in $Z$ by its definition. You're using the Law of Iterated Expectations incorrectly. Btw, I also use LIE, in the step $E(Z)=E(Y)$. I think you're confused by the notation; that's why I assign $E(Y|X)$ its own label.

Comment: Instead of commenting here and there what your answer implies, you should make explicit what you want to say. I really don't care what you said in your answer since I am not the OP.

Comment: @msm Don't be so defensive. I have a comment on your answer so I make it. That's what comments are for, aren't they?

Comment: People are defensive when you become aggressive @yurnero. About your comment, if you really can't figure out what common sense tells about an equality, I really can't help you with your "feeling". I think it is much more informative than your inequality. Improve your post instead of undermining other posts or commenting for them what you wanted to say but didn't.

Comment: @msm I used those words to soften my comments. Strategic mistake. The facts remain: the OP asks whether $A=B$, you say $A=B+C-D$ so you're not settling the original question, you're giving the OP a new puzzle on whether $C=D$. Your answer does contain a different perspective but it certainly does not contain more information. It is also unnecessarily complicated in what it tries to arrive at (your boxed formula).

Comment: First, I cannot see that you explicitly have said whether they are equal or not. So again, start fixing your own post if you are so meticulous. Besides, it is not you who decides what is necessary and what is not. Everyone have the right to leave their answer here whether you think it is necessary or not. Also remember if the OP is puzzled s/he can leave a comment and ask a question. You are not the OP's lawyer or something similar. I won't continue replying anymore to your comments since your argument is just false.

Comment: @msm I show $A\geq B$ always and I nudge the OP in how to construct an example in which $A>B$. That more than shows $A\neq B$ generally. I don't think you understand how it works here. You can post and anyone **not just the OP** can comment and interact with your answer / comments. Your answer entails expanding things using the proof of the LoTV then simplifying (i.e. reversing the expansion) at the last moment using the conclusion of the LoTV. Hence, unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Begin from
$$\mathsf{Var}(Y)=\mathsf{E}Y^2-(\mathsf{E}Y)^2$$
Hence,
$$\begin{align}
\mathsf{Var}(Y)&=\mathsf{E}(\mathsf{E}Y^2|X)-(\mathsf{E}Y)^2\\
&=\mathsf{E}(\mathsf{Var}(Y|X)+\mathsf{E}(Y|X)^2)-(\mathsf{E}Y)^2\\
&=\mathsf{E}(\mathsf{Var}(Y|X))+\mathsf{E}(\mathsf{E}(Y|X)^2)-(\mathsf{E}Y)^2\\
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$${\mathsf{E}(\mathsf{E}(Y|X)^2)=\mathsf{Var}(Y)-\mathsf{E}(\mathsf{Var}(Y|X))+(\mathsf{E}Y)^2}$$

or using the law of total variance,

$$\boxed{\mathsf{E}(\mathsf{E}(Y|X)^2)=\mathsf{Var}(\mathsf{E}(Y|X))+(\mathsf{E}Y)^2}$$

Comment: Note that the Law of Total Variance gives $\text{Var}(Y)-E[\text{Var}(Y|X)]=\text{Var}[E(Y|X)]\geq 0$.

Comment: $E(Z^2)-E(Z)^2=\text{Var}(Z)$ with $Z=E(Y|X)$ so while I haven't written it out explicitly in my answer the information is implicit, especially if you consider when I discuss when the inequality is strict. Note the focus on the variance of $Z$.

Comment: Why do you explain your answer to me @yurnero?! Did I ask something and suddenly forget it?

Comment: Because I feel that in its original form, while containing an explicit formula for $E[E(Y|X)^2]$, this answer fails to address whether $E[E(Y|X)^2]$ is equal to $E(Y)^2$. In your original answer, whether $E[E(Y|X)^2]$ equals $E(Y)^2$ is equivalent to whether $E(\text{Var}(Y|X))=\text{Var}(Y)$ which I don't think is obvious to the OP given what he asks. **So the answer proposes an alternative puzzle instead of settling the original one**. The emphasis on the INequality is to make a negative direct answer to OP's question on equality. Cheers.

Comment: My equality gives as much "negative direct answer" to OP's question as your inequality does. Furthermore, it even tells how much "not equal" they are, **which your answer fails to do so** @yurnero. That is the reason I tell it is much more informative.